# Attempting to retrieve data from front-end using Node/Express w/ body-parser but failing

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express, body-parser

I'm trying to send data from the frontend to a node server using body-parser

Here's the front end code:

```
<body>
    <h1>Donate!</h1>
    <h2>Pick A tier</h2>
<label for="donate-tier-select">Suggested Sponsorship Levels</label>
    <form action="/pay" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="Janeway" value="25">Janeway Tier: $25 monthly</button>
            <button type="submit" name="Kirk" value="15">Kirk Tier: $15 monthly</button>
            <button type="submit" name="Picard" value="8">Picard Tier: $8 monthly</button>
            <button type="submit" name="Sisko" value="5">Sisko Tier: $5 monthly</button>
            <button type="submit" name="Archer" value="3">Archer Tier: $3 monthly</button>
            <button type="submit" name="Nog" value="1">Nog Tier: $1 monthly</button>      
    </form>
</body>
```

Here's the backend/node/express code:

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req,res) => res.render('index'));

app.post('/pay', (req, res) => {
    let dataReceived = req.body;
    console.log(dataReceived);
    console.log(dataReceived.name);
    ...

};
...
app.listen(3000, ()=> console.log('Server Started'));
```

The data received variable, when console logged by itself, displays an object of the attributes from the button clicked, but any call to any of the properties (I assume they share the names of the front end element attributes), I get undefined:

```
Server Started
{ Janeway: '25' }
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I access the attribute values of a given button click on the backend using object dot notation from req.body/dataReceived?

**Main question I'm trying to get answered:**
How would I get body-parser to return the following object with these key value pairs:

`{name: attribute name, value: attribute value}`

with the attributes I have in the my html?

Comment: So the problem is that bodyParser is not parsing it into json but rather keeping it as a string or what?

Comment: @Tyler,  I'm not totally sure. I'm trying to get an object that shows the html attribute as the property and it's html value as the object pair's value in the returned data from body-parser. 
So:
``` { name: Janeway, value: 15 } ```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying read the property "**name**" from "**dataRecived**" object, which does not exist. The property that exists is "**Janeway**", not name.

{ **name**: '**Janeway**' } - if this was your req.body, then you would have got "Janeway" printed in your console. Observe the subtle difference.

In order to read any dynamic property from your request body you can do something like this, which iterates through the object.

```
    let retData = {                                 
       "Janeway" : 25,                             
       "Kirk" : 15 ,                               
       "Picard": 8                                 
    };                                              

    for(let key in retData) {                       
        console.log(key, retData[key]);             
    }
```

Comment: @DeltaFlyer If this has solved your problem, kindly mark it as answer. It will help others to know that this is question has already been answered.

Comment: How would I get the property with the name within req.body then? That's what I'm after.

Comment: It appears to me that "name" property is not at all being sent to your node server. Thats why you see only { Janeway: '25' } when you do console.log(dataReceived).

Comment: I reproduced your form and api end point, I see that the html doesn't send they key "name" to the server. It sends only the value that is set for the attribute "name" in the form element.